New to React. Wokring on a Youtube tuorial that is a bit outdated so mine isnt the exact same but I cannot get passed this one part
I am running my spring boot application on port 8080 and have set up a react app on visual code. I created a proxy for the connection. I am using render() to  have a 'Loading' piece pop up as the information is grabbed but its stuck at Loading and I dont know why.
Here is the Category.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Category extends Component {

    state = {
        isLoading : true,
        Categories : []
    }

     async componentDidMount(){
        const response = await fetch('/api/categories');
        const body = await response.json();
        this.setState({Categories :body, isLoading: false});
        }
     render(){ 
        const{Categories, isLoading} = this.state;
        if(isLoading)
            return(<div>Loading......</div>);
        
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                {
                    Categories.map( category =>
                    <div id={category.id}>
                        {category.name}
                    </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Category;


And...... Here is the index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Category from './Category';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
//import * as serviveWorker from './serviceWorker';

//ReactDOM.render(<Category/>, document.getElementById('root'));
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Category/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();
//serviveWorker.unregister();


I am trying to get passed this loading state and show the actual categories.
This is from the developer tools with the connection
Developer Tools

how is that related to the Java Programming Language, why the [tag:java] tag?

Why is this tagged java and spring-boot?

I think may be an issue with the url used in fetch(). if the proxy isn't working as expected try this instead: since your server runs on 8080 it should be fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/categories'). Do check the network tab in the developer console on chrome or Firefox will let you know if the request is successful or not

I added a screen shot to the question after I used your suggestion and I am still not getting passed the Loading part

the response has a 200 status code so the fetch request is succeeding, the console shows some errors though do check those by clicking on the console tab
